# Why lambda inside map is not running?

Tags: lambda, concurrency, java-8, java.util.concurrent, concurrent.futures

I am trying to learn concurrency and lambdas in java 8. But my code is not entering lambda block inside map.

```
List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    isbnList
    .stream()
    .map(isbn -> (CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
        try {
            List<String> pageContents = getUrlContents(webLink + isbn);
            return new Book(
                parseBookTitle(pageContents),
                isbn,
                parseRank(pageContents)
            );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    })).thenApply(a -> bookList.add(a))
    );
```

While debugging, code is exiting at .map line and I m getting empty bookList. Sequential code for same is giving me correct result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A stream pipeline is *lazy*. Without a *terminal operation*, your stream pipeline is not even executed. [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is an *intermediate operation* so it won't trigger pipeline execution.

Now you could add a [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) step with the lambda expression `cf -> cf.join()` for joining on your created `CompletableFuture` instances for your pipeline to be executed and wait for each of your async futures to complete. But doing this way will defeat the whole purpose of using asynchronous futures, because you're submitting them sequentially and waiting on the completion of each one before submitting the next one.

Better yet, you could convert your stream to a *parallel* stream, use `map` with your async lambda body directly by removing the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` part and collecting with `collect` for a similar effect without the extra clutter.

```
List<Book> bookList = isbnList.parallelStream()
    .map(isbn -> {
        try {
            List<String> pageContents = getUrlContents(webLink + isbn);
            return new Book(
                parseBookTitle(pageContents),
                isbn,
                parseRank(pageContents)
            );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Further reading: [Stream operations and pipelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) in the stream API javadoc.

Comment: Replaced map with forEach but still control is not going inside lambda block. Please suggest.

Comment: You're submitting asynchronous tasks to the common fork-join pool, but you're not waiting for the results. You need to make sure your tasks are finished. Go back to using map but joining for your async futures in a forEach. I'll update my answer. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that `Collection`s have the `parallelStream()` method, which shortcuts the `stream().parallel()` steps.